# synchronized not synchronizing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized

`synchronized` does not appear to work as I had expected. Shouldn't it make the code within the brackets atomic with respect to a separate block of code that is `synchronized` by the same object?

I'm finding that it's not synchronizing at all within my code.

```
private Object movementMutex_ = new Object();    

// Thread
public void run()
{
    while (run_)
    {
        synchronized(movementMutex_)
        {
            if (timeToMove_)
            {
                Log.v("meh", "timeToMove_ was true, moving");
                makeMove();
                Log.v("meh", "Move Complete. Setting timeToMove_ to false");
                timeToMove_ = false;
                Log.v("meh", "timeToMove_ is now false");
            }
        }
    }
}


// Called by a different thread so that this thread knows when to make a move
public void move()
{
    Log.v("meh", "awaiting movementMutex in move()");
    // Synchronizing so that timeToMove_ doesn't get set true while in the middle of moving and thus setting it back false prematurely
    synchronized(movementMutex_)
    {
        Log.v("meh", "move called, setting timeToMove_");
        timeToMove_ = true;
        Log.v("meh", "timeToMove_ is now true");
    }
}
```

Looking at the Log printouts, I'm seeing them print in an unexpected order. The statements in bold should, from my understanding of synchronized, be uninterpretable by the non-bold printouts yet this is not the case and the very thing I'm attempting to avoid is occurring: I'm missing the next move because I set it true when it was still already true and promptly turned it false.

```
 08-12 10:47:19.860: V/meh(27639): awaiting movementMutex in move()  
 08-12 10:47:19.985: V/meh(27639): move called, setting timeToMove_  
 08-12 10:47:19.985: V/meh(27639): timeToMove_ is now true  
 08-12 10:47:19.985: V/meh(27639): **timeToMove_ was true, moving**  
 08-12 10:47:20.352: V/meh(27639): awaiting movementMutex in move()
```

This next line should not be possible. It's not awaiting the movementMutex!

```
08-12 10:47:20.352: V/meh(27639): move called, setting timeToMove_  
08-12 10:47:20.360: V/meh(27639): timeToMove_ is now true  
08-12 10:47:20.360: V/meh(27639): **Move Complete. Setting timeToMove_ to false**  
08-12 10:47:20.360: V/meh(27639): **timeToMove_ is now false**
```

Comment: Does the makeMove() function call the move() function? I.e., are both synchronized blocks being accessed by the same thread? This would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Are you saying that nested synchronized calls wouldn't result in deadlock but instead would pass through since it already has access? It's not equivalent to a "wait()" call for a mutex? If so, it may be possible that the code progression causes it to call itself indirectly. If that is correct, feel free to answer and I'll mark it answered.

Comment: While it was difficult to find documentation on nesting the synchronized call, a simple test showed me that it indeed ignored it. It does not result in deadlock. Therefore I'm quite certain that was my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Tutorial doc on lock reentrancy (nested sych calls): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, a thread is capable of reentering its own synchronized lock. The "makeMove()" function call was actually the instigator of calling "move()" which meant it was executing under the same thread and thus not being locked out. In short, the below code would not cause a deadlock; it would execute without a problem and this is what I was experiencing.

```
synchronized(movementMutex_)
{
    synchronized(movementMutex_)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```