# Synchronized doesn't synchronize

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, synchronized

I have a custom adapter that it's associated with a `ListView` in my `MainActivity` class and when I press on one of the items of the List (`setOnItemClickListener` method) I execute an `AsyncTask` to retrieve the info from the database and send it into a `bundle`.

Therefore, I have to wait until the `AsyncTask` finishes to send the info retrieved in the `bundle`.

For this purpose, I created an `interface`:

```
public interface OnCarListener {

    void onCarCompleted(String c);

    void onCarError(String error);
}
```

And I have my `AsyncTask` in another class:

```
class findCar extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {

    private final OnCarListener mListener;

    public findCar(OnCarListener listener)
    {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Integer... idCar) {

            String nameCar = "";

            //Here the code to retrive the info

            nameCar = obj.getString("name"); 

            //Now nameCar = "Car1"

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        return nameCar;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String c) {

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onCarCompleted(c);
        }
    }
}
```

And I execute my `AsyncTask` (in my `MainActivity`) as follows:

```
new findCar(new OnCarListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCarCompleted(String c) {

        synchronized (c) 
        {
            name = c;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCarError(String error) {
    }
}).execute(idCar);
```

And after executing the `AsyncTask` I throw the bundle:

```
bundle.putString("name", name);
```

**Note:** I send more info with the `bundle` but I omitted it to simplify the question.

It should work in my opinion but in the first click in one element of the `List` the `name` isn't being passed by the `bundle`, **just in the second and the rest of the clicks** I made at the same or in the rest elements of the `List`, it works.

**Expected result:** `AsyncTask` will be executed and until it finishes the rest of the code shouldn't work. It is clear that it's not what it's doing right now.

**What I want to know:** Why the `synchronized` doesn't work in the first iteration? I mean, when I have the `List` and I click on one of the elements of the `List` the information of the element it's show (in another Activity) but the value `name` it's not shown.

If I go back and I do one or more clicks on the same element (or a different one) from the `List`, in all of them appears the value `name` correctly.

Why in the first iteration it doesn't work?

And I have another question: Why if I quit the `synchronized` as `adelphus` said in his answer, any of the times that I click on the elements of the `List` the value `name` appears?

---

I tried the solution in this question: [synchronized not synchronizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923296/synchronized-not-synchronizing) but still doesn't work.

What could I do? *(Without changing the logic of the program)*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you understand what `synchronized` does - it creates an exclusive lock on a given object to create ordered access to a section of code. When multiple threads attempt to enter a synchronized block (with the same lock object), only one thread will be allowed to continue into the block at a time.

In your code, you're synchronizing on the String parameter `c`. Since no other threads will be accessing this parameter, `synchronized` has no effect here.

Since your interface callback is being called on the UI thread (via `onPostExecute()`), you can just set the bundle value in the callback:

```
void amethod() {

  final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  new findCar(new OnCarListener()
  {
      @Override
      public void onCarCompleted(String c) {
            bundle.putString("name", c);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCarError(String error) {
      }

  }).execute(idCar);
}
```

Comment: Now any of the times I press on the elements of the List the value `name` it's stored in the bundle.

Comment: According to your answer I tried to synchronize my `bundle` because it seems that it is trying to insert the new value when the bundle it's being sending, but I get the same error as in your case. Any of the times the `name` it's being send.

Comment: Your question was to solve putting the value into the bundle **when the first item was clicked** - that is what this code does. Yes, it will also replace the name whenever you click an item - but I have no idea how you are using your bundle or where/how you are sending it.

Comment: What do you need to know? I'm really stuck here. In my bundle I just pass some info and the `name` that I have to retrieve from the database. My problem it's that I can't get out this `name` from the `AsyncTask` to `MainActivity` in which the `AsyncTask` it's executed. Thanks for your time!